# Uncheck checkbox 1 when checkbox 2 is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked, unchecked

I have a pretty simple question - I'm thinking - but I cannot solve it myself.

I have two checkboxes:
One with value Yes, the other with value No.

I need a script of some sort to help me uncheck one when the other is checked. So if I check checkbox no. 1 - checkbox no. 2 automatically gets unchecked - and vice versa. One of the checkboxes - and only one - must always be checked. And no - i cannot use radio buttons in this case.

Would be great if it could be done i jQuery - but any help would do :)

Thanks in advance

Robert

Comment: Why can't you use radio buttons? This is *exactly* what they were designed for.

Comment: "And no - i cannot use radio buttons in this case." - do elaborate.

Comment: If you cannot use radio buttons, then I guess there is some problem with your analysis, because what you want is precisely the radio button behavior. You should give a step back and think why on earth you cannot use radio buttons. Do not reinvent the wheel again.

Comment: Because I need the "No" checkbox to be hidden since the user shouldn't be able to see it. I could use a radio button, but if the user then activates "Yes" and decides he wants to undo that he can't because the no button isn't visible.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way that I could think of to do this is with the following:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        var group = this.name;
        $(this).siblings('input:checkbox[name="'+ group + '"][checked]').removeProp('checked');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZNWVe/1/).

However there are some caveats, the above uses `removeProp()`, which is limited to jQuery 1.6 (and above, presumably). Prior to 1.6, it should be possible to substitute `removeAttr('checked')` instead.

Please, though, reconsider using `<input type="radio" />` elements, this is ***precisely*** what they're designed to handle and work with.

---

**Edited** following comment from Robert (in comments, below):

> I got this working as planned, BUT...in my form I have another group of checkboxes, and they get the restriction as well, although they have completely different names. But I need the user to be able to pick more than one of these checkboxes. It seems as though the script affects all checkbox groups. I actually thought that by putting in name="'+ group +'" one would limit the function to those checkboxes with a name starting with the word "group". But that seems not to be the case.

The selector that assigns the `change` event-handler is `$('input:checkbox')` which selects/applies to *all* checkboxes on the page.

To apply it to only those checkboxes in a particular group, you could use:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="checkboxGroupName"]').change(
    function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeProp('checked');
    });
```

References:

- [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/).

Comment: Hi David. Thanks alot. I got this working as planned, BUT...in my form I have another group of checkboxes, and they get the restriction as well, although they have completely different names. But I need the user to be able to pick more than one of these checkboxes. It seems as though the script affects all checkbox groups. I actually thought that by putting in name="'+ group +'" one would limit the function to those checkboxes with a name starting with the word "group". But that seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#checkbox1").bind('click', function(){ $("#checkbox2").removeAttr('checked'); });
$("#checkbox2").bind('click', function(){ $("#checkbox1").removeAttr('checked'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#checkbox_1').change(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#checkbox_2').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#checkbox_1').prop('checked', false);
            $('#checkbox_2').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });

    $('#checkbox_2').change(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#checkbox_1').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#checkbox_2').prop('checked', false);
            $('#checkbox_1').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

Edit: That should work now :-)

Comment: Hi Thorsten. Thanks a lot. #checkbox_1 and #checkbox_2, what are they relating to in my checkboxes? Id? name?
I have these two:
<input type="checkbox" name="contact[]" id="contact_yes" value="Yes" />
<input type="checkbox" name="contact[]" id="contact_no" value="No" />

So what would I put into your code instead of #checkbox_1 and #checkbox_2. Yeah, I know I'm a complete idiot :)

Comment: It should be enough to replace "checkbox_1" with "contact_yes", and "checkbox_2" with "contact_no" all over the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChkBoxClicked() {
    $("#chkBoxList_0").bind('click', function () { $("#chkBoxList_1").removeAttr('checked'); });
    $("#chkBoxList_1").bind('click', function () { $("#chkBoxList_0").removeAttr('checked'); }); 

    if (($('#chkBoxList_0').is(':checked')) || ($('#chkBoxList_1').is(':checked'))) {
        if ($('#chkBoxList_0').is(':checked')) { alert('chkBoxList_0'); return false; }
        if ($('#chkBoxList_1').is(':checked')) { alert('chkBoxList_1'); return false; }
    } else {
        alert('non of the chkBoxList'); return false;
    }
}
```

This is how I did it

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".checkbox1" ).click(function(event) {
    $(this).parents('tr').children('td').children('.todos').prop('checked', false); 
    });
    $( ".checkbox2" ).click(function(event) {
        $(this).parents('tr').children('td').children('.checkbox1').prop('checked', false); 
    });
```

This basically states that when checkbox1 is checked, and the user attempts to check checkbox2, checkbox1 will be unchecked.